# retrieve the value of an ArrayList inside a repeating function

Tags: java, loops, firebase-realtime-database, arraylist, methods

I'm trying to retrieve the array list generated in the function `recuperarPessoasModelo()`, but it only runs much later than I need so the value passed to `revelaPessoas()` is null, does anyone know any way I can run this function and just get the value after `recuperarPessoasModelo()` is executed? I can't put it inside because since it has a for loop it will run X times and generate a repeating list

The .Json in the DB looks like this:

```
Perfil{
       PcCPoh01wscJj7jJBQQorme7Rqq1{
                                    status:online
                                    name: Carl Johnson
                                    age: 21 
                                    sex: male}
       t3IeEKy7XxdGeLYRxw2G1djNHdp2{
                                    status:online
                                    name: John Marston
                                    age: 33 
                                    sex: male}
}
Requisicoes{
 t3IeEKy7XxdGeLYRxw2G1djNHdp2{
                             Enviadas{
                                     PcCPoh01wscJj7jJBQQorme7Rqq1{
                                                             idPessoa:PcCPoh01wscJj7jJBQQorme7Rqq1
                                                             status: Aguardando
                                                                 }
                                     }
                              }
}
```

**the class in question:**

```
public class Perfil_outter extends AppCompatActivity{

    private List <RequisicoesCitty> requisicao = new ArrayList<>();
    private List <ModeloPerfil> pessoaQuestao = new ArrayList<>();
    private String idComp;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     
     carregarIds();
     revelaPessoa()
    }

    public List<ModeloPerfil> getPessoaQuestao() {
        return pessoaQuestao;
    }

    public void setPessoaQuestao(List<ModeloPerfil> pessoaQuestao) {
        this.pessoaQuestao = pessoaQuestao;
    }

    public void carregarIds(){
        Log.d("Part 1", "Working");

        DatabaseReference firebaseRef = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebaseDatabase();
        DatabaseReference idsRef = firebaseRef.child("Requisicoes");
        Query refId = idsRef.child(usuarioAtual.getId()).child("Enviadas").orderByChild("id");
        refId.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {


                for(DataSnapshot ds: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    RequisicoesCitty reqSnapshots = ds.getValue(RequisicoesCitty.class);
                    Log.d("IdPessoas",reqSnapshots.getIdPessoa());
                    requisicao.add(reqSnapshots);
                }
                carregarRequisicoes();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }

    public void carregarRequisicoes(){

        if(requisicao.isEmpty()){
            Log.d("Não encontrado", "Nenhuma requisição Citty");
        }

        for(RequisicoesCitty requisicao: requisicao) {
            Log.d("Part 2", "Working");
            DatabaseReference firebaseRef = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebaseDatabase();
            Query requisicoesEnviadas = firebaseRef.child("Requisicoes").child(usuarioAtual.getId())
                    .child("Enviadas").child(requisicao.getIdPessoa());

            requisicoesEnviadas.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    RequisicoesCitty reqSnap = snapshot.getValue(RequisicoesCitty.class);
                    idComp = reqSnap.getIdPessoa();
                    recuperarPessoasModelos();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });
        }
    }



    public void recuperarPessoasModelos(){
        Log.d("Part 3", "Working");

        DatabaseReference firebaseRef = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebaseDatabase();
        Query pessoas = firebaseRef.child("Perfil").child(idComp);
        pessoas.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                ModeloPerfil pessoas = snapshot.getValue(ModeloPerfil.class);
                pessoaQuestao.add(pessoas);
                setPessoaQuestao(pessoaQuestao);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }

    public void revelaPessoas(){

        for(ModeloPerfil modelo: getPessoaQuestao()){
            Log.d("Funcionar", modelo.getNome());
        }
    }
}
```

did you understand my problem? my goal is to get the value `modelo.getNome()` inside of `revelaPessoas` back and display but it runs sooner than it should

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `recuperarPessoasModelos` each time that `carregarRequisicoes` loops through one of its `for(RequisicoesCitty requisicao: requisicao) {`. This is totally fine, but I'm guessing that `recuperarPessoasModelos` is not handling these multiple calls correctly.

If you only want to call `recuperarPessoasModelos` once all `requisicao` are done, you can check a counter like this:

```
List snapshots = new List(); //  a list to track the snapshots we have already loaded
for(RequisicoesCitty requisicao: requisicao) {
    Log.d("Part 2", "Working");
    DatabaseReference firebaseRef = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebaseDatabase();
    Query requisicoesEnviadas = firebaseRef.child("Requisicoes").child(usuarioAtual.getId())
            .child("Enviadas").child(requisicao.getIdPessoa());

    requisicoesEnviadas.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            snapshots.add(snapshot); //  add snapshot to list
            RequisicoesCitty reqSnap = snapshot.getValue(RequisicoesCitty.class);
            idComp = reqSnap.getIdPessoa();
            if (snapshots.size() == requisicao.size()) { //  check if we got all of them
                recuperarPessoasModelos();
            }
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            throw error.toException(); //  never ignore errors
        }
```